# OFB output jth-block expression clarification

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, stream-cipher, ofb

Stalling says:

> OFB encryption can be expressed as
>
> Cj = Pj⊕E(K, Oj-1)
>
> where
>
> Oj-1 = E(K, Oj-2)
>
> Some thought should convince you that we can rewrite the encryption
> expression as:
>
> Cj = Pj⊕E(K, [Cj-1 ⊕Pj-1])

Is he implicitly saying that

> [Cj-1 ⊕Pj-1] = Oj-1

? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is he implicitly saying that
>
> [Cj-1 ⊕Pj-1] = Oj-1

Yes, this is true.

> ? If yes, why?

Well, we know that:

$$C_{j-1} = P_{j-1} \oplus E(K, O_{j-2})$$

(this is the first formula, replacing $j$ with $j-1$), and we know that:

$$O_{j-1} = E(K, O_{j-2})$$

Combining the two, we get:

$$C_{j-1} = P_{j-1} \oplus O_{j-1}$$

or, in other words:

$$C_{j-1} \oplus P_{j-1} = O_{j-1}$$